# Symmetric unitary matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Hi,

Given a complex unitary matrix $U$, can we find a real orthogonal matrix $K$ such that the product $KU$ is a complex symmetric matrix.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried just playing with the $2\times 2$ cases?

Comment: yes, but i could not see the results even in that case.

Comment: i need this result to see that 
if u is a complex unitary matrix, then $U=K.exp(iX)$ for $K$ is a real orthogonal matrix and $X$ is a real symmetric matrix. This is called polar decomposition for unitary matrices. For n=2, ı know that every symmetric unitary matrix can be written of the form 
$exp(iX)$ where $X$ is real symmetric.

Answer (score 1):

Use https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153837/proof-of-existence-of-square-root-of-unitary-and-symmetric-matrix.

$U^TU$ is symmetric and unitary, so there exists a symmetric unitary $V$ such that $V^2=U^TU$. Set $K=VU^{-1}$, then $K$ is unitary and $K^TK=I$. Therefore, $K$ is real orthogonal as desired.